# How to print a multiplication table in java

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, methods

I have to create a program that prints a times table that 
1)Has multiple methods.
2)Reads in two numbers where one is the upper limit and the second will be how deep the table goes (rows and columns essentially).  It's a step up from the restriction of just square tables where it can only be, for example, 10x10 or 12x12.
3)Has a loop so that the user can run it again with different input.
4)Use Scanner to read I/P.
The output is supposed to look like this when you input 3 for the first number and 8 for the second number:

[image]

But it comes out like this: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edeux.png)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TimesTableRewrite
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {   
        Scanner in;
        in = new Scanner (System.in);
        boolean runAgain = false;
        header();
        String response;
        do 
        {   

            printTable();
            System.out.println("\nDo you want to go again? Y or N?");
            response = in.next();
            if ((response.charAt(0)=='Y'||response.charAt(0)=='y'))
                {
               runAgain = true;
                }
            else
                {
               runAgain = false;    
                }
         }
       while (runAgain);
        footer();       
    }

    public static void printTable()
    {
        Scanner in;
        in = new Scanner (System.in);

        int height;
        int length;
        System.out.println("Enter the first number to set up how far down you want the table to go.");
        height= Integer.parseInt(in.next());
        System.out.println("Enter the second number to extend the table horizontally");
        length = Integer.parseInt(in.next());

        for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++ )
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= length; j++ ) //j is number of columns
            {
                if (i<height)
                    System.out.format("%4d", + i*j);
                else
                    System.out.format("%4d", + i*j);
                if (i==height)
                {
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }   
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++ )
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= length; j++ ) 
            {
                if (j<length)
                    System.out.format("%4d", + i*j);
                else
                    System.out.format("%4d", + i*j);
                if (j==length)
                {
                    System.out.println();
                }   
            } 
        }
    }
    public static void header()
    {
        System.out.println("This program will help you practice your times tables!");
        System.out.print("This newer version will allow you to go beyond the 12 times tables!");
        System.out.println("It will let you choose your upper limit \nand how deep the times table will go.");
        System.out.println("Let's go!");
        System.out.println("\nPlease enter two numbers to generate a multiplication table.");
    }   
    public static void footer ()
    {
        System.out.println("That's all folks! See you next week!");
    }           
}
```

Comment: I'd strongly suggest reading the [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: I'm not asking you guys to do my homework for me.  As you can see, I've already done most of it, I just need help in figuring out why it's coming out the way it is.  I've spent hours working on it, I can't get it to work, so god forbid if I ask for some guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++ )
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= length; j++ ) //j is number of columns
    {
        if (i<height)
            System.out.format("%4d", + i*j);
        else
            System.out.format("%4d", + i*j);
        if (i==height)
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }   
}
for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++ )
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= length; j++ ) 
    {
        if (j<length)
            System.out.format("%4d", + i*j);
        else
            System.out.format("%4d", + i*j);
        if (j==length)
        {
            System.out.println();
        }   
    } 
}
```

With this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++ )
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= length; j++ ) //j is number of columns
    {
        System.out.print(i * j);
        System.out.print("\t"); //We add a tab after each number to form every column.
    }   

    System.out.println(); //We add a berakline for each row.
}
```

Comment: You can use a ternary operator with your "runAgain" logic. Like this: 
runAgain = (response.charAt(0)=='Y' || response.charAt(0)=='y');